# The meaning of open sets in the context of charts of a set

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-spaces, geometric-topology

I will give a little background. I have just started a course on differential geometry and prior to this, I had only about vector spaces. I had not read a single thing about topology or topological spaces or anything such. So prior to taking this course, I only knew meaning of open sets in the context of vector spaces.

In the beginning of this course, all we were taught about topology is the axioms that a set of subsets of a parent set  should satisfy. And that exact set of a topology is an open set. Now I am having trouble in reconciling the idea of open sets in both contexts (one being vector spaces and other being topologies).

My problem arises because in the definition of charts of a non empty set, it is required that the image of chart map is an open set in $R^n$. So what does open set mean here? In lecture notes they do mention something like whenever $R^n$ is considered as a vector space, it is equipped with its standard topology. What is a standard topology (I googled it but all the sources assume different backgrounds and it would require me to again read something else hence I ask here)? And does it mean that any open set in the vector space sense is also open in the context of its standard topology and vice versa?

Comment: It is the topology induced by the metric i. e. a basis is given by the open balls in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: @Mr.Fox Could you please elaborate more? What is meant by topology induced by the metric? I have only read about normed vector spaces; can I simply replace the norm of the difference of two vectors by the metric everywhere and proceed to understand?

Comment: Sure! Yes, as the standard metric in $\mathbb{R}^n$ (and in normed vector spaces in general) is induced by the norm in the way you wrote: the distance of $x$ and $y$ is $|x-y|$. Topology induced by the metric means that you want to have the open balls as open but don't want to make any more constraints than that, so you take the open balls i.e. the sets of the form $\{x\in \mathbb{R}^n | |x-p|<r\}$ (for some $p\in \mathbb{R}^n$ and positive $r$) as a basis and consider the sets and only the sets that can be written as the union or finite intersection of these as open sets.

Comment: @Mr.Fox Thank you! When you say “you want to have the open balls as open but don't want to make any more constraints than that”, does it mean that our topology includes open balls (which are open in the sense of the metric we have) so that they are open when talking in the context of topology? And no more constraints means we don’t add any more sets to the topology (except the ones which end up there by virtue of being derived from the basis)?

Comment: Yes, that's right.